# SMTPClient class error

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I´m  trying to send an email through gmail using this code:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("admin@XXXXXX.com");
            msg.To.Add(destinos);
            msg.Subject = "XXXX";
            msg.Body = "XXXX"
            //msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(archivo + ".pdf"));
            //msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(archivo + ".xml"));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.google.com", 587);//587 465 
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@XXXX.com", pass);

                client.Send(msg);
```

However it fails, giving this exception:

```
16/07/2012 03:45 p.m. ERROR: Error al enviar correo. Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal System.Net.WebException: No se puede resolver el nombre remoto: 'smtp.google.com'
   en System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout)
   en System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   en System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   en System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) Exception actual: Void Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)
```

The exception is in spanish, I don't really like that either but it says something like:

```
There was an error when sending the mail, Couldn't resolve host smtp.google.com
```

I have checked the current google parameters and they look good for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the ifnromation below taken from google and looks like you got smtp host wrong
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

```
Configure your client to match the settings below:
Incoming Mail (POP3) Server - requires SSL: pop.gmail.com
Use SSL: Yes
Port: 995
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS3 
    or SSL: smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465
Account Name:   your full email address (including @gmail.com or @your_domain.com)
Email Address:  your email address (username@gmail.com or username@your_domain.com)
Password:   your Gmail password
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't resolve the dmain. Should be smtp.GMAIL.com

see:

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Answer (score 1):

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
```

(whew)